Geogebra specify length with brace
Is it possible to specify segment length with a brace or arrows, like below?

Credit: https://mrchasemath.com/2018/01/17/geometric-proofs-of-trigonometric-identities/

Credit: https://senecalearning.com/en-GB/revision-notes/a-level/maths/edexcel/pure-maths/5-4-3-angle-addition-formulae
https://www.reddit.com/r/geogebra/comments/1ansqgi/brace_objects/ I'm not sure how the linked demo works.

You can use segments with an arrow end style or use the vector command between points

@Paul do you mean create a parallel segment just for display? I thought about that but it seems redundant

I have removed the tag [tag:geogebra] tag from your post.  I think that the tag is too niche to be of much use on this site.  Moreover, we generally ask that users not create new tags without first running it by the community.  See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35451/ .

@XanderHenderson Apologies, though there are a decent number of questions concerning geogebra.

You can recreate the arrows and text in your second picture with line segments and a text box. These can rescale and move with the image if dimensions change. I don't know what you mean by redundant

@Paul I mean the arrow is another line segment instead of just a label right? That seems to be ok. Can you write an answer?

As an example suppose that you have a horizontal side with end points at A and B. You can create a segment 0.3 below this with
Segment[(x(A), y(A)-0.3), (x(B), y(B)-0.3)]
Right click the segment and go to Properties, Style. Change the Begin and End Style to arrows.
For a label click on the TextBox command then the screen. Put in your text, which can be dynamic (changes as values change) and/or include Latex. Right click the Textbox, go to Properties, Position and in Starting Position put (1/2(x(A)+x(B)), y(B)). Move the Textbox to where you want it with the mouse. As your original line changes the Textbox should move with it.
The GeoGebra home page has a very good and active user forum. This would be a better place to ask questions like this.
